# Mocking a queue in Kotlin with Mockito does not seem to work

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, junit5

I have a simple named service which uses a queue:

```
@Named
class OrderFormService @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: OrderFormRepository
) {
    private val queue: Queue<OrderForm> = LinkedList()

    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("service")

    fun getNextOrderForm(input: GetNextOrderFormInput): GetNextOrderFormPayload? {
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("queue is empty")

            val forms: List<OrderForm> = repository.findTop1000ByImageTypeAndImageState(input.type, input.state)

            forms.forEach {
                queue.offer(it)
            }
        }

        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            return GetNextOrderFormPayload(queue.poll())
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

While trying to unit test this I want to mock the queue:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal class OrderFormServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private val queue: Queue<OrderForm> = LinkedList()

    @Mock
    lateinit var repository: OrderFormRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var service: OrderFormService


    @Test
    fun givenValidInputAndFilledQueueWhenGetNextOrderFormThenReturnPayload() {
        // given
        val expected = createOrderForm()
        val expectedPayload = GetNextOrderFormPayload(expected)

        given(queue.isEmpty()).willReturn(false)
        given(queue.poll()).willReturn(expected)

        // when
        val input = GetNextOrderFormInput(ImageType.NUMBER, ImageState.UNCLASSIFIED)
        val result = service.getNextOrderForm(input)

        // then
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expectedPayload)
    }
}
```

But the queue is always empty. So I guess the queue is not getting mocked correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Things I have tried:

1. Making queue not final:

```
...
var queue: Queue<OrderForm> = LinkedList()
...
```

2. Using `Mockito.mock`:

```
...
var queue = Mockito.mock(Queue::class.java)

`when`(queue.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false)
`when`(queue.poll()).thenReturn(expected)
...
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to mock the queue, which is, BTW, not an injected dependency of your service.

Comment: Dont get why there should not be a reason to mock the queue. I need to fill it to test the behaviour with a filled queue. without mocking it: how should I fill it? And because it is not injected I dont use `@InjectedMock` but `@Mock`

Comment: So, fill it. Make your mock repository.repository.findTop1000ByImageTypeAndImageState() method return a non-empty list, and calling getNextOrderForm() will fill the queue. Your test should verify the contractof the method, which is that every invocation of the method returns the next element of the collection, until there is no next element, and the collection is fetched again.

Comment: And that is exactly not what I want. I have already covered that test case. The queue can be filled without the repository getting called.

Comment: No, it can't. The only place in the code you posted where the queue, which is private, is filled, is from the collection returned by the repository.

Comment: First call: Queue is empty, it is getting filled with 1000 values from the repository.
Second call: Queue is not empty. The repository is not getting called.

Comment: So, test that. Make your repository return 2 values. Call the method once. Test that the repository has been called and that the method returned the first of the 2 elements. Call the method again. Verify that the repository has not been called again, and that the method returns the second element. Call the method again. test that the repository has been called a second time to refill the queue, and that the method returned the first element. The fact that this uses a queue internally is an implementation detail that the test should ignore.

Comment: Ofcourse I could do that. But that was not the question. I asked how I can mock the member variable.

Comment: When someone asks "which kind of car should I buy to cross the ocean", the proper answer is: you need a plane or a boat, not a car.

Comment: But I did not ask how I can test the case when the queue is not empty (how I can cross the ocean), I asked specifically how I can mock the member (how I can use the plane) :)

Comment: All the cases can be tested without mocking the queue. And that's, IMHO, the proper way to test your code. You decided you need to mock, although, IMO, it's not the right thing to do, and it's unnecessary.

Comment: You can't. The instance field is final, and can thus not be reassigned by Mockito.

Comment: I suspected this already. So I changed it to `var` with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queue is not marked as `@Autowired` or part of the constructor, thus Mockito cannot mock it.

In order to make this work (haven't verified it though), define your constructor like this:

```
@Named
class OrderFormService @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: OrderFormRepository,
    private val queue: Queue<OrderForm>
) { }
```

Now, in order to have the queue initialized in your regular program, you have to define a bean for it, something like:

```
@Configuration
class QueueConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun queue() : Queue<OrderForm> = LinkedList()
}
```

Furthermore, you should keep in concern that `@InjectMocks` only will use one injection method. So you can't mix constructor initialisation with property setters or field injection.

Also have a look at `@MockBean`. This replaces the bean globally and can be more convenient to use. It has the drawback that it dirties the context, resulting in context reinitialization and potentially slower tests if they aren't sliced properly.

**EDIT:**

Another alternative would be to set the mock manually (samples not verified, hope they work work you). I recommend using https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin to make the Mockito syntax more kotlinish.

Setting the mock manually requires to make the queue a publicly settable property:

```
@Named
class OrderFormService @Inject constructor(
        private val repository: OrderFormRepository
) {
    var queue: Queue<OrderForm> = LinkedList()
}
```

Then, you assign the mock in your test:

```
internal class OrderFormServiceTest {

    private val queue: Queue<OrderForm> = mock {}

    @Mock
    lateinit var repository: OrderFormRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var service: OrderFormService

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        service.queue = queue
    }
}
```

There's one issue with this though: depending on the framework you use, your `OrderFormService` might be initialised only once. When setting the queue, you change the global object which might affect other tests. To mitigate this, `@DirtiesContext` on your test will ensure that the whole context is rebuilt (which impacts test performance). This is more or less the same which `@MockBean` would do for you (with the same performance impact). You can also clean the object yourself though.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way to mock a member variable when it is not autowired? I mean maybe a bean would make sense for the queue as soon as I would need the same queue in several services. But as long as this is not the case it seems a bit overkill.

Comment: There are definitely ways to do so. I'm answering with the assumption that you want to use the functionalities offered by ```MockitoExtension``` in conjunction with its annotations, staying as close to the examples you provided.
You can still create your mock manually and inject the mock manually. But then you have to deal with accessibility of that variable. 
From an encapsulation point of view, especially when you want to test independent from the queue, injecting the queue should be more suitable.

Comment: I see. Im already using annotations and `MockitoExtension`, you are right. But im really curious how mocking would work for simple memember variables.

Comment: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin has some nice examples. Basically, you just create a mock variable in your test and can assign it to the field - provided it has a setter.

Comment: Another option would be to make the queue publicly accessible, make it a ```var``` and then do something like: ```service.queue = mock {}``` . But as this exposes the internals of your service, I wouldn't do this in production code.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Could you add these options to your existing answers so I can accept it?